# My response from api is undefined on frontend

Tags: mysql, node.js, angular

I got list of items from my database mySql and also button 'edit'.
When I clicked edit (by id) I want to see all fields filled by data.
But I only have in my console: undefined 
If I tested my api by postman it works fine.

There is how I am getting list.

```
{
    const id = this.actRoute.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');

    this.studentApi.GetStudent(id).subscribe((res: any) => {
      console.log(res.data);
      this.subjectArray = res.data;
      console.log(this.subjectArray);
      this.studentForm = this.fb.group({
        id: [res.id, [Validators.required]],
        domain_id: [res.domain_id, [Validators.required]],
        source: [res.source, [Validators.required]],
        destination: [res.destination]
      });
    });
  }
```

There is my api.service.ts

```
GetStudent(id): Observable<any> {
    const API_URL = `${this.endpoint}/read-student/${id}`;
    return this.http.get(API_URL, { headers: this.headers })
      .pipe(
        map((res: Response) => {
          return res || {};
        }),
        catchError(this.errorMgmt)
      );
  }
```

And there is my route

```
studentRoute.get('/read-student/:id', (request, response) => {
  const id = request.params.id;
  con.query('SELECT * FROM students WHERE id = ?', id, (error, result) => {
      if (error) throw error;
      response.send(result);
  });
});
```

There is response from 'postman'

```
[
    {
        "id": 5,
        "domain_id": 2,
        "source": "tester0700@test.pl",
        "destination": "testw@test.pl"
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like the response is an array, containing an object.

In that case, there is no need to use `res.data`, as that would imply the returned observable, `res` has a property named `data`, and that you are trying to access the value within that property. You can simply assign `res` to the `subjectArray` property. I am pretty sure `res` would be defined.

```
this.studentApi.GetStudent(id).subscribe((res: any) => {
  console.log(res);
  this.subjectArray = res;
  // handle the rest here.
});
```